# Gremlin - get list of vertices mapped to edge type for each vertex

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I'm trying to do something similar to SQL join operation with Gremlin in Azure Cosmos.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this. If we take the example of TinkerPop modern graph example-

[image]

I want to retrieve all vertices but for each vertice, also get a map with keys being the relationship type and value being an array of vertices of that relationship. For the vertex `id:1`, that would be:

```
name: marko
age: 29
relationships: {
    created: [<node id:3>],
    knows: [<node id:2>, <node id:4>]
}
```

I'm unable to understand how to achieve this, or even if it can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `project` step:

```
g.V().has('name', 'marko').project('name', 'age', 'relationships')
.by(values('name'))
.by(values('age'))
.by(outE().group().by(label()).by(inV().fold()))
```